# Docker: Devices cgroup isn’t mounted (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install docker on an Ubuntu 16.04 on a remote webserver. However, I get an error that is really frustrating me. I have been installing docker a lot of times already, also on this OS, but this never happened.

I am stuck at `sudo apt-get install -y docker-engine`, when docker-engine cannot be installed:

```
~# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2017-03-05 17:47:20 CET; 32s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 18194 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.567753592+01:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please e
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.569299675+01:00" level=error msg="'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please e
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.591796895+01:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.592394882+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.592410368+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.592421460+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.592427398+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.592458649+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
dockerd[18194]: time="2017-03-05T17:47:20.592490516+01:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
dockerd[18194]: Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

I added root to the group, also I found the advice to add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"` to the file /etc/default/grub, but that file does not exist!

I also tried `sudo apt-get install cgroupfs-mount` but without success :-(

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10):

So, folks. There is no solution, unfortunately. The reason is the architecture of the remote webserver, a hosted VM. 
My provider told me all VMs use the same kernels in one environment and therefore dokker can't access it.

The only option now is to switch to another server.